How to use a Transferhook + Permanent Delegate together
I am trying to come up with a system that would restrict holders of a specific token from transferring them between wallets, effectively making them soulbound. In this system, only the permanent delegate should be able to transfer tokens on behalf of users.
From my research, it seems that I should use the "Permanent Delegate" and "Transferhook" token extensions.
My idea was to create a Transferhook that prevents transfers to any address however, I am not sure if this would play nice with the ability for a Permanent Delegate to transfer the tokens on behalf of users.
To build this system, would the Permanent Delegate somehow need to be added to the Transferhook so that any transfers they try and make are ignored by the restrictions of the Transferhook?

Yes i think that should be possible. You can maybe change this white list example up a bit to make it work:
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/token-2022/transfer-hook/whitelist/anchor/programs/transfer-hook/src/lib.rs
Just need to make sure to add it and remove it from white list in the same transaction.
smth like this:
Transaction

InstructionAddToWhiteList
checkedTransfer
InstructionRemoveFromWhiteList

Note though that this example is not really scalable to thousands of users since it saves the white list in one account. Better approach would be to use a PDA per account. But for your usecase it should work.

I don't think a whitelist is needed. The transfer hook receives the owner and the mint, so it simply needs to check that the received owner is the permanent delegate, which is stored on the mint
